# Local fields from outer class unaffected by Runnable code

Tags: java, android, multithreading

This has been killing me lately. I'm making a quick settings tile that should show as active or inactive based on whether it can communicate with a specific machine over a socket. Here are my declarations:

```
public class WakeUpTileService extends TileService {
    private static volatile boolean online;
    private final TimerTask timerTask;
    private Timer timer;
```

Here's the constructor:

```
public WakeUpTileService() {
    super();
    online = true;
    timer = new Timer();
    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean shouldBeOn = false;
            try {
                Socket s = new Socket();

                // 3000 is the timeout in milliseconds.
                s.connect(myInetSocketAddress, 3000);

                // Connection was successfully established.
                s.close();
                shouldBeOn = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Connection failed.
                // shouldBeOn is already false.
            } finally {
                if (shouldBeOn != WakeUpTileService.online) {
                    WakeUpTileService.online = shouldBeOn;

                    // This method causes onStartListening() to be called
                    // on the main thread so I can update the Tile.
                    requestListeningState(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        new ComponentName(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            WakeUpTileService.class
                        )
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Here's where the timer gets started:

```
@Override
public void onTileAdded() {
    super.onTileAdded();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 60000);
    // At the moment I have it checking once per minute
    // For debugging purposes. I plan to make it less frequent.
}
```

And here's the code that uses the value of `online` to update the Tile. This gets called on the main thread after `WakeUpTileService.online = shouldBeOn;` in the `TimerTask`.

```
@Override
public void onStartListening() {
    Tile t = getQsTile();
    if(WakeUpTileService.online)
        t.setState(Tile.STATE_ACTIVE);
    else
        t.setState(Tile.STATE_INACTIVE);
    t.updateTile();
}
```

When I step through the code in the debugger, the `TimerTask` code is definitely finished before `onStartListening` gets called, and within the context of the `TimerTask`, `online` holds the correct value. Then, when `onStartListening` is called, `online` seems to revert to the value it had at the beginning.

Thoughts I've had about what might be going on:

- The `online` being referenced in WakeUpTileService is somehow not the same object as is being referenced in the Runnable code (that's why I made `online` static and used `WakeUpTileService.online` instead of just `online`.)
- The assignment to `online` is actually not happening before `online` is read by `onStartListening()`. Again, when I stepped through the code with the debugger, this doesn't appear to be happening, and just by looking at the code below, this doesn't seem reasonable.

I don't know what else could be happening here. Please help!

---

Update: korolar suggested that the two classes might have been loaded by different classloaders, and after some investigation, I found that that *is* the cause. My service is being loaded by `dalvik.system.PathClassLoader` and `java.util.Timer` is being loaded by `java.lang.BootClassLoader`. I don't, however, know how to work around or solve this issue. Can anyone provide some suggestions?

Comment: is `onStartListening()` inside `WakeUpTileService` ?

Comment: Yes, `WakeUpTileService` contains `online`, `timerTask`, a Timer object called `timer`, a constructor, `@Override onTileAdded()`, `@Override onStartListening()`, and `@Override onClick()`.

Comment: You say, "online begins as true", but where is the code that sets it true?

Comment: I'll just put the constructor in the question, I was trying to keep the question short.

Comment: what if you use a `final AtomicBoolean` instead of `volatile boolean`, see if it improves things.

Comment: I actually did try that, same issue. The boolean value inside the AtomicBoolean appeared to have the correct value immediately after the assignment, but then when the value was being used in onStartListening it was unchanged. Same for other variables I've constructed this way.

Comment: Is it possible, that setting the static field and reading it are executed in the context of different classloaders?

Comment: Maybe... I'm not familiar with the concept of a classloader! I'll look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I'll let you know what I eventually did to fix it.

Apparently using the java.util.Timer class at all is generally bad practice in Android programming. Instead, I rewrote my program using the Android `AlarmManager` class and `IntentService`. That completely bypasses the classloader problem.